# Generator for Pascals triangle

Tags: python, list, function, generator, pascals-triangle

I made a generator of Pascals triangle values in list

```
    import math

    def combination(n, r):
        t = int((math.factorial(n)) / ((math.factorial(r)) * math.factorial(n - r)))
    
        return t

    def pascal_triangle():
        """Return numbers from pascal triangle"""
   
        count = 0
        while count>=0:
       
            for element in range(count + 1):
           
                t =combination(count, element)
                yield t
            count += 1
    lst= [next(pascal_triangle()) for _ in range(10)]
    print(lst)
```

The result is list of 1 only, but should be  1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 .....
Where am i wrong?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

For each element of your list comprehension `pascal_triangle` is being called anew, starting at the beginning.  What you want instead is:

```
pt = pascal_triangle()
lst= [next(pt) for _ in range(10)]
print(lst)
```